# How to execute a bash script from within my python project

Tags: bash, python-2.7, pycharm

I am writing some automation to control a simulator. I am also using `WebDriverAgent` along with `openatx` python bindings in pycharm. There are some things that are fast using cURL in a bash script and some methods that are stronger in the python solution. I want to use a mix of both. I have imported `bashSupport` into pycharm and would like to execute a bash script from within my file system of the project.

I have tried `subprocess` import and `os` but it doesn't seem to be executing my script. Here is an example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['launch_wda.sh'])

with device.session('com.apple.mobilesafari') as app:
print app.orientation
app(label="Address").tap()
app(label="Address").set_text("facebook.com \n")
```

the `launch_wda.sh` is in my file structure of the project. Is my syntax incorrect or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

1. Add `./` before script name. As this could be some path related issue.
2. Try adding shell=True if you are not under Posix system and you do not have something like this `#!/bin/sh` as a first line of your bash script.
3. Last but not the least, check the permissions for the bash script.

Hope this helps.